# What happens when two processes hold an election using bully algorithm simultaneously

Tags: distributed-systems, synchronization

A coordinator is used to sychronise the usage of resources in a distributed system.

[The Bully Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_algorithm) is a method to elect a new coordinator in a distributed system when the current coordinator disappears for some reason.

I am just wondering what happens when two processes realise the demise of the coordinator simultaneously and both decide to hold an election using the Bully Algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

Both processes will anounce themselves. However, the one with the highest indentifier will become the leader. For example, 3 and 4 announce themselves. 3 asks who has an id greater than me, and 4 responds. Then 3 knows 4 is the new leader. 4 does the same. No process replies. 4 tells everyone that he's the new leader.